# Is Objective-C++ a superset of both C++ and Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Or in more practical terms: If I compile a file containing just Obj-C code or just C++ code under Objective-C++, can I be sure they'll behave exactly as they did before? In what ways might they differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More or less, that is true;   anything that compiles under either C++ or Objective-C will compile with the Objective-C++ compiler.

However, there are some edges where this doesn't hold true and a handful of behavioral differences.

I'm not aware of any specific at-runtime behavioral differences, though.   The differences should generally show up during compilation and mostly as problems caused by C++'s "enhanced" notion of types.

Operator overloading can be exceedingly problematic, however.   If a body of code makes extensive use of operator overloading, that can cause issue when mixing Objective-C in for the first time.  But, again, typically as compiler warnings and rarely as at-runtime bugs.

Comment: That's the answer I was hoping for!

Comment: (although see my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a superset of C only. You can mix C++ with Objective-C - that is called Objective-C++ - however there are certain rules that you have to follow.
Here you can see all the rules that have to be followed: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html

EDIT: This is a quote from the developer website: "Apple’s Objective-C compiler allows you to freely mix C++ and Objective-C code in the same source file. This Objective-C/C++ language hybrid is called Objective-C++. With it you can make use of existing C++ libraries from your Objective-C applications.".

So it clearly says, that the mixture of C++ and Objective-C is called Objective-C++, but that is not a superset of C++, but it's two languages that with some rules can be used together. (For instance you can't mix objective-c and c++ classes during inheritance, but there are others as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's at least one example of valid Objective-C code that's not valid Objective-C++:

```
void SayHello()
{
    char* this = "hello!";
    printf("%s", this);
}
```

(what someone would be doing naming a variable 'this', I don't know)

Comment: Yup; you can come up with a handful of small sharp edges like this.  I believe `id` can make things barf, too, in certain circumstances.